# How do I auto-click a button on a webpage using only a URL?

Tags: android, html, reactjs

Basically, I need to open a webpage and click a button using nothing more than a URL.

[Here's a picture of the button in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOJvH.png)

Would it be possible to do that with the button in the picture? I want to connect a donate button in an Android app to an existing button on a webpage, and can't think of any other way to do that. Feel free to provide alternatives as well!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should provide a specific URL that you want to open in the browser or better make a HTTP GET request as suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5996691/1101730 - in case you want to integrate PayPal.