# Are Donate buttons allowed for apps on the Android Market?

Tags: android, google-play

There are conflicting opinions at [PayPal Donations on Android Apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5053722/paypal-donations-on-android-apps)

Some say no, but one comment is:

*There's a similar discussion on Google Groups which basically says that donations are allowed as long as you don't offer additional functionality for that money. 
Meaning no functionality is enabled after the donation is made.*

So...does anybody know the current and official policy on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing in the [market's policy](http://www.google.com/mobile/android/market-policies.html) prohibits this kind of feature. Like your quote says, if you want users to pay for certain feature, make a paid application.

Answer (score 1):

That quote you made sounds pretty solid, so I am going to say, yes you can. Have you tried?

Comment: Nope, because the contradicting quotes sound pretty solid, too.