# In-app Paypal button for Android programs

Tags: android, paypal

I would like to develop an application that allows me to accept donations via PayPal. I have read that this is allowed as soon as no additional services are activated (donations vs purchase) ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5053722/paypal-donations-on-android-apps)).

If the user has the PayPal app installed, I would like to open it and fill the required fields.

Is there an Intent to do so or must I open a web page with Paypal button URL?

Answer (score 0):

I'm 100% sure you have to open a web page with Paypal button URL

What I use this for my donation buttons and have it set as a picture button:

```
`Donate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.paypal.com/your_paypal"));
                startActivity(browserIntent);
            }
        });`
```

to get the link version click the email version when setting up the button.
if the donations are for you i would name the button "support the devs"